# Return focus to host from Radmin viewer

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a keyboard shortcut to release the focus back to the host machine when using Radmin?

In VMware you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> and then any keypresses will go back to the host. Is there an equivalent in Radmin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way to do this.  I asked the question last week on Radmin's support forums, but haven't heard a response.  Here's the [post](http://www.radmin.com/support/forum/index.php?PAGE_NAME=read&FID=30&TID=15235).  If they answer it, I'll update this answer.

EDIT: 2011-08-23
They replied to the post confirming there's no shortcut.  It's been added to the "wishlist."  No idea if it's a coming soon or several versions out...